# mysql java preparedstatement insert if not exist

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, where-clause, insert-into

i try to fill data into my databse. But i don't want dublicates based on the time. I don't care about the dublicates, because i don't lose any data.
After a long search i finally found, that you can't use `WHERE NOT EXIST` with an `INSERT INTO`.

But now i got the next problem. I tried these two approaches but none of these works.

```
      /*
      preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM gpsdata.data where time=?) "
            + "Begin "
            + "INSERT INTO gpsdata.data VALUES (default, ?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "+
              "END");
      */
      preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO gpsdata.data VALUES (default, ?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "
            + "SELECT ? FROM gpsdata.data WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM gpsdata.data where time = ?)");
```

Both gave me some mysql syntax errors. I can't figure out what is wrong. I am new to mysql. The last try gave me at least a different error:

> MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual... ... to use near 'SELECT 1448982118099 WHERE NOT
>   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM gpsdata.data where time =14') at line 1

Before the check for dublicates, the code was running fine. So it should be the new statement.

Regards,
Eric

EDIT: I don't want to copy my data into an other table.

Comment: Do you want to move data to an other table?

Comment: Bind variables are for transferring data between SQL and the client code (Java, in your case,) not for transferring data within a query. `INSERT ... SELECT` is for copying records from one table to another. I think neither of these is what you are trying to do. Would it make sense to make the `time` column a unique index, or part of a unique index?

Comment: @mokarakaya No i don't want to do that. I just want to insert new data into my table. But i don't want to create dublicates with these inserts

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax I was thinking about this unique idea. I don't know how to do this yet.

Comment: Post your `CREATE TABLE` statement and maybe we can help pick out the index candidates. Look specifically for a column or group of columns whose concatenated value must always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

`?` is not a valid parameter in `SELECT ?`. You have to literally name a column.

Answer (score -1):

In order to connect *insert with parameters* part with *condition* part you can use *select from dual*.
I have tried the statement below with Oracle.

```
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO gpsdata.data select 'default', ?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? from dual
            WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM gpsdata.data where time = ?)");
```

ps: please be aware that you use time variable twice.

Comment: The question is about MySQL.

Comment: I bet it's same for MySQL